# Контроллировать I/O другой программы на C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, c

Здравствуйте. Возможно тема немного сбивает с толку, по этому поясню проще: мне нужна программа на **С/С++**, которая сможет запустить переданную ей в аргументы другую программу, а потом дать ей кое-что на вход (input), подождать пока она (переданная ей программа) сделает свое и получить её вывод (output). И ещё: программа, которую я передам в аргументы моей программе-оболочке -- скрипт на **Python 3**, может это важная деталь. Программа будет под **Linux**. Собственно мне нужно узнать через какие функции можно это сделать (я имею ввиду делать ввод в программу и получать её вывод).

Comment: если можно сохранять в файлы input и output то можно просто сделать вызов system с параметров [название] < input > output

Comment: Понял. Но нельзя без доп. файлов?

Comment: Конечно, можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону `popen` - например, [здесь](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) или [здесь](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html) - это вам не поможет?

Comment: С popen есть одна большая проблема, она может либо только писать на ввод программы, либо только читать. для двухсторонней связи следует использовать собственный fork/exec перенаправив файловые дескрипторы

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Это не будет работать если надо и писать в скрипт и читать от него.

Answer (score 8):

В простейшем случае можно сделать 2 пайпа ([pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)), через первый будете писать скрипту, а через второй читать от него, потом создать процесс ([fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)), в котором можно переключить ([dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)) дескрипторы пайпа на `stdin` и `stdout` скрипта и запустить его (например, [execl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl)).

Вот примитивный пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2)
    errx(EX_USAGE, "Usage: %s cmd [args]\n", av[0]);

  pid_t pid, cmd;
  int pin[2], pout[2]; // пара пайпов для обмена со скриптом
  if (pipe(pin) || pipe(pout))
    err(EX_OSERR, "pipes");

  if (!(cmd = fork())) { // запуск скрипта с аргументами
    close(pin[1]);
    close(pout[0]);
    dup2(pin[0], 0);     // заменим stdin скрипта на наш ввод
    dup2(pout[1], 1);    // перекинем stdout скрипта на наc
                         // stderr скрипта остался тем же, что и у нас
    execvp(av[1], av + 1);
    err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "exec %s", av[1]);
  }
  if (cmd == -1)
    err(EX_OSERR, "fork");

  // эти дескрипторы более не нужны
  close(pin[0]);
  close(pout[1]);

  char *str = 0;
  size_t ssize = 0;
  ssize_t l;

  // для примера читаем stdin и передаем в скрипт
  while ((l = getline(&str, &ssize, stdin)) > 0)
    if (write(pin[1], str, l) != l)
      err(EX_IOERR, "write pipe");

  close(pin[1]); // пошлем EOF на stdin скрипта

  // читаем вывод скрипта и для примера печатаем его
  FILE *progout = fdopen(pout[0], "r");
  while (getline(&str, &ssize, progout) > 0)
    puts(str);

  free(str);
  int status;
  errno = 0;
  if ((pid = wait(&status)) != cmd) {
    if (errno)
      err(EX_SOFTWARE, "wait");
    else
      errx(EX_SOFTWARE, "wait unexpected PID %ld (waited %ld)", 
           (long)pid, (long)cmd);
  }
  if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("%s exit code %d\n", av[1], WEXITSTATUS(status));
  else
    printf("%s terminated by %d\n", av[1], WTERMSIG(status));

  return puts("End") == EOF; 
}
```

Тут могут быть "подводные камни" (особенно если захотите "интерактивной работы"), поскольку `FILE *` с пайпом (в отличии от терминала) буферизуется (и вывод `fprintf`/`fputs` не будет реально выводиться в пайп по строкам), а также пайпы  имеют ограниченный размер, что может привести к взаимной блокировке процессов.

Например, Вы пишете скрипту, он возвращает свои результаты через пайп, и если вы этот пайп не читаете, то скрипт "повиснет" на своей операции записи (пайп заполнен, а его никто не читает).

Для корректного решения такой ситуации надо читать ответы скрипта по мере их появления, для чего посмотрите на [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) или [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

А также для решения подобных задач полезно посмотреть на *псевдотерминалы* (проще всего начать с вызова [forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty), ну и не забудьте про все SEE_ALSO :-)).